# How to fix unit attribution of last lines of systemd logging before exit?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have a systemd service which logs to stdout. From there, systemd captures STDOUT and writes it to the journal.

I use a common idiom for handling an error where I `echo` some diagnostics, then exit with a non-zero error code:

```
echo "my final error";
exit 1;
```

My problem is that this final `echo` line makes it to the journal, but is not properly associated with my "unit". By looking at `journalctl -o json-pretty`, I can see what the difference is. The final logging lacks the properties _SYSTEMD_CGROUP and _SYSTEMD_UNIT.

What I think is happening is a kind of race condition. I suspect that that the bash script doesn't wait for `journald` to fully process the before moving on to the exit line. So the `exit` line is reached before `journald` finishes processing the log entry. `journald` tries to look up the `unit` that sent the logging, but now can't find it since the unit is no longer running.

If I'm right, I could probably work around the issue by putting `sleep 1` before my `exit 1` statement, but is there a better way to get the final logs property attributed?

I'm using `systemd` version 229 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What happens when the log line is sent instead to stderr? That is less likely to be block or line buffered like stdout is, and thus less likely to be lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mark-stosberg, this is a known issue: [journald is unable to attribute messages incoming from processes that exited to their cgroup, due to /proc vs SCM_CREDS race](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913)

You can find a workaround there: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2913#issuecomment-219702148

> try [`SyslogIdentifier=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#SyslogIdentifier=)
>
> > Sets the process name to prefix log lines sent to the logging system or the kernel log buffer with.
>
> and run `journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=unit + UNIT=unit + SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=id`

Answer (score 2):

I researched this, and it appears to be a [known issue with systemd that there is a pull request for](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/2280).

The fix involves caching the metadata for the service, so that even if the service has exited, the metadata for it is still available to properly categorize the last few logs.

It's also considered an [open bug in CoreOS](https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/373), which uses systemd.

The bug is also tracked on the systemd freedesktop.org bug tracker under as:

- [Bug 50184 - systemd-journal sometimes loses _CMDLINE, _COMM, _EXE, _SYSTEMD_CGROUP, _SYSTEMD_UNIT](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50184)

Further testing found the issue of missing log attribution is more severe with *user* units-- I assume that's a separate issue. For *system* units, the race condition is relatively small and adding `sleep 1;` just before exit in the service script may add enough padding before the the last log printed and the exit to workaround the issue.